# How can I evaluate my model when the the testing data are too few and the generated results don't match testing data

Tags: machine-learning, bioinformatics

I have a bioinformatic data set includes a very large negative examples (let's say 30000 examples) and just a few positive examples (let's say 150 positive examples). Since I need to feed an enough amount of positive examples (let's say 135 examples) to learn a model. I just have a few positive examples left for testing set. The problem is the positive predicted results don't match at all with the amount of positive examples (15 positive examples) in testing set. So are there some ways I can evaluate my learning method to know whether it's truly good or not?  Thanks very much for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are evaluating your model is correct. You may not like the result, but that is not statistics. Try jack-knife, or k-fold cross-validation, so you use more of your data to build a model. Try some of the ideas to define variables in case of rare events (for example, search for the notes of this talk ( http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/programs/scientific/11-12/DLSS/ ). See ( http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/audio/ )

Comment: I think the link is broken.

Comment: Hi VictorZ, I'm using k-fold cross-validation. However, the problem is my predicted results are in 3-dimension or 4-dimension, so the variety of results is large and it seems not to match well with my testing data. By the way, can you please fix the broken link? Thanks very much.

Comment: I fixed the link

Comment: your results are in three dimensions but they are either positive or negative?

Answer (score 1):

You may find the strategy of [Percolator](http://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v4/n11/abs/nmeth1113.html) useful. It takes two datasets, a decoy (all negative) and a target (positives and negatives), and uses them to create a very robust model. More modern versions include 3-fold [cross validation.](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/13/S16/S3)

The way it works is to try to separate positive examples as a difference  with the decoy database. Then, iteratively, trains a SVM using the good identifications as positives and all the decoy as negatives.

*Disclosure:* I was working at that lab with both first authors, but not on Percolator.

Comment: not sure how this addresses the questions, which centers on validating a model.